# Algorithm: Picking n items of different weights to obtain an average item-weight

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, distribution, mathematical-optimization

I have 5 folders each containing 'n' files of size 10KB, 500KB, 1MB, 5MB and 30MB.
Now I need to pick **exactly** 15000 files from these folders and place them into a new folder such that I pick at least one file from each of the folders **and** the average file size remains around 1MB.
I've tried with working on weighed average distribution as well as along the lines of this problem http://goo.gl/uAHOk1 but couldn't reach any conclusion.

Is this problem solvable in polynomial time?

### EDIT

From comments:

1. For the sake of clarity, you may consider each folder have exactly 16k files.
2. By around 1 MB I meant the average file size to be in the range of 1 to 1.5 MB. For example, if I had to pick exactly 5 files keeping in mind the constraints of my problem, the only solution would be picking one file from each folder. Then, the average file size would become 7.3MB

Comment: What does "around" 1MB mean? Is there some specific interval?

Comment: It seems that based on the fact that you need mathematical help on the formula, and not on how to write this code, this question would be much more suited (and answered insanely quicker) over at [http://math.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @harold I guess they mean to *minimize | average - 1MB |* since there is no other goal in the problem's formulation...

Comment: Your problem formulation is unclear, at least to me.  Does *each* folder have `n` files?  If not, how are they distributed amongst the folders?  How big is `n`, do you ever have capacity constraints where you can run out of files of a particular size?

Comment: @pjs For the sake of clarity, you may consider each folder have exactly 16k files.

Comment: @harold By around 1 MB I meant the average file size to be in the range of 1 to 1.5 MB. For example, if I had to pick exactly 5 files keeping in mind the constraints of my problem, the only solution would be picking one file from each folder. Then, the average file size would become 7.3MB

Comment: If you pick 5 from each folder and then 30 of 10KB, it'll be "around 1MB" for some definition of "around". Then just pick 14965 files of 1MB (do you have them or are there limits?). But this seems like a cheat, it's certainly not an optimization algorithm.

Comment: Well I mean 1 from each folder (5 in total), but you get the idea, I just satisfied the constraints one by one.

Comment: @harold Agreed,this can be one solution. However I'm looking for a generalized formula or algorithm to find such answers. For example what would be the solution if one folder contains files of size 489KB and likewise(varying weights). The solution to the problem might not be exactly an optimization algorithm but more of a distribution algo.

Comment: I arrived at this solution by just taking 1 of each, then correcting the average size (it was too large, so I added tiny files until it was good enough), the for the leftover you can pick the "closest" size until the average wanders off, then fix it again, and so on.. here that was easier because there are files with the target size which you can just pick forever

Answer (score 2):

**If you want the average size to be as close to your value as possible**, this problem resembles the following ILP:

```
s_ij = size of file i in folder j  [Parameter]
X_ij = select file i from folder j [Binary variable]

max  Sum_ij s_ij * X_ij
such that
Sum_ij s_ij * X_ij <= 15,000 * average_size
Sum_ij X_ij = 15000
Sum_i X_ij >= 1  forall j
```

Which is pretty much a bin packing problem with one additional dimension and constraint (the one file per folder).
As Harold mentioned, we can start by going through each folder and selecting a file - for instance the smallest one. This can be done in polynomial time.
What's left is a bin packing problem where you can choose from any file in any folder to fill the gap between 15,000*average_size and the sum of pre-picked files. Bin packing is known to be **NP-hard** though, so you won't be able to solve this in **polynomial time**.